# VScode не видит заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

Собрал библиотеку `fltk`. Заголовочные файлы лежат по пути `/usr/local/include`, библиотеки — по пути `/usr/local/lib`.

В файл `c_cpp_properties.json` в `"includePath"` добавил строку `"/usr/local/include"`. Но VSCode почему-то не видит `.H` файлы, у которых в начале стоит `Fl` (например `FL/Fl_Window.H`), он видит просто файлы без этого, и файлы у которых в начале стоит `fl` (например `FL/fl_types.h`). При этом он не выводит ошибок, если я добавлю тот же самый `FL/Fl_Window.H`, но зато ругается на файлы `Fl/Fl_JPEG_Image.H` и `Fl/Fl_GIF_Image.H`.

Компилятор тоже выдал ошибку на `Fl/Fl_JPEG_Image.H`:

```
fatal error: Fl/Fl_JPEG_Image.H: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так Вы же сами пишите:

> например FL/Fl_Window.H

, а после:

> Fl/Fl_GIF_Image.H.

FL и F**l** - разные имена директорий.